# How to swipeleft and swiperight

Tags: javascript, swipe

Apologies in advance - this is such a fundamental question:
Why are swipeleft and swiperight not working?

```
(function() {
    $('img').on('swiperight', swipeRight);
    function swipeRight(myEvent){ 
        myEvent.stopPropagation();
        alert('swipeRight');
    };

    $('img').on('swipeleft', swipeLeft);
    function swipeLeft(myEvent) { 
        myEvent.stopPropagation();
        alert('swipeLeft');
    };
})();
```

I've loaded jQuery, but do I need to load a entire library like jQuery Mobile or Angular?
I just want to slide from 1 picture to the next.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at some javascript frameworks such as Hammer JS http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/

Comment: Good idea.  I see that hammer.js is mentioned in 
JavaScript Weekly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add touch-swipe using [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/).

Using Touch Punch is as easy as 1, 2…
Just follow these simple steps:

1. Include jQuery and jQuery UI on your page.

   ```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Include Touch Punch after jQuery UI and before its first use.

   Please note that if you are using jQuery UI's components, Touch Punch must be included after jquery.ui.mouse.js, as Touch Punch modifies its behavior.

   ```
   <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
   ```
3. Make the object you want to swipe draggable.

   ```
   <script>$('.selector').draggable();</script>
   ```

Comment: Wow!  Thanks Foreever!  Love them plugins!

Comment: OK, after sleeping on it I've decided to check your answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

[Standard jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) doesn't define a `swiperight` or `swipeleft` event. [jQuery Mobile does](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swiperight/), however. You'll have to load that library to utilize those event handlers.

Comment: Oh... So I would have to load jQuery Mobile... I was hoping to use twitter bootstrap.

Comment: As far as I know, bootstrap's JS only defines events for the plugins that it includes. [According to their documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-events), they don't officially support 3rd party libraries either, so there may be some conflicts you'll have to resolve if you use bootstrap events + jQuery/jQuery Mobile.

Comment: OK, well, I've had some experience with jQuery Mobile, so I guess my answer is to use it.  Thanks!

Comment: @Phillip I don't think you should use jQuery MObile just for getting 'swipe' event. IMO use jQueryMobile if your are planning to develop a mobile application website. Maybe you could add Swipe event using jQuery UI Touch Punch.

Answer (score 2):

A element doesn't have a swipeleft or swiperight event handler. What you need to use touchstart and touchend. So for touch here are all the event handlers:

1. touchstart
2. touchmove
3. touchend
4. touchenter
5. touchleave
6. touchcancel

With these you can add by using jquery ON method and your function.

To calculate swipe left and swipe right you have to do a caculation using touches[0]. Read the article!!

Here is a resource that helped in in developing for touch screens using vanilla js. 
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents2.shtml

Comment: Oh ok, thanks! I don't necessary need vanilla js, but I'll read the article.  I just need to swipe from 1 picture to the next.

Comment: Jquery doesn't do touch, you can use jquery mobile to accomplish without much javascript code.Here is the answer:  http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents3.shtml